# SQLite-Net Extensions Newtonsoft.Json version depedency

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

In the last version of the nuget package `"SQLite-Net Extensions PCL"`, the required version of Newtonsoft.Json has been bumped to >= 6.0.0.5.
Is there any particular reason for that ?
Because of that I can't update the package in my Azure Mobile Service project as Azure Mobile Service depends on Newtonsoft.Json = 6.0.0.4... annoying... :)

Or is there another way ? (except from building form source)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Json library is required for serializing `TextBlob` properties as Strings. There are some suggestions to remove this dependency and move the `TextBlob` logic to another package to avoid this kind of issues, but it's not implemented yet.

Currently last version (1.3.1) of [Azure Mobile Services](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/) requires Newtonsoft.Json >= 6.0.0.4 , so installing 6.0.0.5 would make both of them work.

Comment: I actually was talking about the backend package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables/), which sadly depends on Newtonsoft.Json (= 6.0.4)... 
The idea was to reuse my PCL Sqlite DAL (used with MVVMCross and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android) on the server side too and make some sync in between (struggled too much already with EF).
But it seems that Azure Mobile Services and Sqlite don't pair that well as the sqlite .db file is "hard" to read/persist.  
Thanks for your answer anyway, I actually end up using Parse by lack of time.